# Laravel 5.2 pass data to multiple cross platform

Tags: php, laravel, api

Would it be possible to pass data from different platform.

I used API to pass data from another platform but when I do multiple platform like 
form A -> A -> B. But when passing at B the data is lost

Is any other way to make this possible like temporary value/data?

I was creating a chatbot using Flow XO platform. When I pass data to my controller and go to FLOW XO using http request the data is null

This is my JS callback getting the org id

```
function messengerReadyOrg() {
    var data = {};
    var question;

    // Get organization ID
    var org_id = document.getElementsByName('flowxo_orgid')[0];
    var organization_id = org_id.dataset.orgid;
    data.organization_id = organization_id;

    //Get Organization ID for get school list
    var xhr_org_id = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr_org_id.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/themartialarts/whitebelt/public/getOrgId?org_id=" + organization_id);
    xhr_org_id.send();
    xhr_org_id.onload = function() {
        if (xhr_org_id.status === 200) {
            var orgdata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            alert('Fetch ' + orgdata.organization_id + ' successfully.');
        } else {
            alert("Error");
        }
    }

  }


//My Routes 

Route::get('/getOrgId','LeadController@getOrganizationID');
```

//Controller

```
  //Fetch Organization ID
public function getOrganizationID(Request $request){
    $data['organization_id'] = $request->org_id;
    return response()->json($data);
    }
```

Comment: Where is `$data` defined? You are getting the data as Query String Parameter. If you are new to Laravel, then in PHP, we get the value by $_GET.

Comment: I mean this. the $data is from the callback.

public function getOrganizationID(Request $request){
    $data['organization_id'] = $request->org_id;
    return response()->json($data);
    }

Comment: the <script> holds data set with a value from a data base. which is in my callback so i was trying to pass that data from my callback to my controller and from controller using api to FLOW XO which is a 3rd party for my chatbot